# How to shorten code when I do a variable assignment in a condition in Dart?

Tags: conditional-statements, dart

Here's the ugly long code:

```dart
var i;
if(true)
  i = 1;
else
  i = 0;
```

When I try this:

```dart
var i = (true ? 0 : 1);
```

it doesn't work resulting in an error on the following line. I guess I was a bit inattentive reading Dart's syntax specs, so can anybody show me the right way?

Comment: What's the error you are getting? I just get a 'Dead code' warning.

Comment: That's not directly an answer and maybe just an error on SO, but the two snippets produce different results. `var i = (true ? 1 : 0)` would be the equivalent, you switched the "if" and "else" there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This looks perfectly fine from a syntax point of view. You can omit the parentheses.

I get a warning 'Dead code' at '1' with your example because of 'true'.
The Darteditor shows you a hint that you wrote code that may contain a bug because he knows your expression can never evaluate to 1 because of the hardcoded 'true'.

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
    var b = true;
    var i = b ? 0 : 1;
}
```

doesn't produce a warning.

Comment: What about check to `null`? `bool b; var i = b ? 0 : 1;` `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool' of 'boolean expression'.`

Comment: This is a runtime error due to a not initialized variable. That has nothing to do with syntax and IMHO not with the question.

Comment: Question is "How to shorten code when I do a variable assignment in a condition in Dart?". Your answer to main question not take that if shorten code in your manner you can get runtime error. `var i = (b == null ? false : true) ? 0 : 1;`

Comment: Good point. @snitko 's example is a bit too simplified due to his `true` literal.

Comment: Ok, thanks. For some reason it just didn't work in my case. I'll check my code again.